# DialogFragments for users to enter data

Tags: android

I've been trying to make a dialogFragment for my app but it's proving to be quite hard to do with a lack of examples available on the internet. Below is an image of something similar that I'd want.
[image: dialogFragment Example]

Having a similar design to the image above would be great. I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct and so far this is what I have done.

[image: My attempt at dialogFragment]

I don't know how to lay out the dialogFragment like the way it has been done for the first picture and I'm not sure how to get fields where my users can enter data to. Below is the code I currently have.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Reminders extends Activity
{

    Button add, edit, remove;
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reminders);
        initializeVariables();

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog();
            }
        });

        List<ListViewItem> items = new ArrayList<Reminders.ListViewItem>();
        items.add(new ListViewItem()
        {
            {
                ThumbnailResource = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
                Title = "Item1 Title";
                Date = "Item1 Date";
                Time = "Item1 Time";
                Amount = "£0.00";
            }
        });
        items.add(new ListViewItem()
        {
            {
                ThumbnailResource = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
                Title = "Item2 Title";
                Date = "Item2 Date";
                Time = "Item2 Time";
                Amount = "£0.00";
            }
        });

        CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, items);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void initializeVariables()
    {
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEdit);
        remove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRemove);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LVReminder);
    }

    class ListViewItem
    {
        public int ThumbnailResource;
        public String Title;
        public String Date;
        public String Time;
        public String Amount;
    }


    void showDialog() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = MyAlertDialogFragment
                .newInstance(R.string.dialog_title);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "New");
    }

    public void doPositiveClick() {
        // Do stuff here.
        Log.i("FragmentAlertDialog", "Positive click!");
    }

    public void doNegativeClick() {
        // Do stuff here.
        Log.i("FragmentAlertDialog", "Negative click!");
    }

    public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
    {

        public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title)
        {
            MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("title", title);
            frag.setArguments(args);
            return frag;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

            return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int whichButton) {
                                    ((Reminders) getActivity())
                                            .doPositiveClick();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int whichButton) {
                                    ((Reminders) getActivity())
                                            .doNegativeClick();
                                }
                            }).create();
        }
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any advice on how to get a DialogFragment like the one in the first pic I provided. Thanks to anyone who tries to help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the layout that you wish to achieve via XML document. Then from there you could change your `onCreateDialog` as follows:

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        int title = getArguments().getInt("title");
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_layout, null); 

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(v) 
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int whichButton) {
                                ((Reminders) getActivity())
                                        .doPositiveClick();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int whichButton) {
                                ((Reminders) getActivity())
                                        .doNegativeClick();
                            }
                        }).create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be better for me to just include the buttons in the XML layout, instead of having .setPositiveButton and .setNegativeButton

Comment: Depends where you want the buttons. If you just need a Ok and cancel at the bottom of the dialog then I think how you have it is fine. If you need more in various places then do them via the XML. Also I would agree with Warpzit, that layout example is rather complicated for a phone and you may want to consider a "lighter" layout for phone with multiple dialogs as an option.

Comment: Yeah at the bottom of the dialog would be great. The layout in the example pic is basically what I want to do. Give users the option to set a reminder, so they pick the date they want to be reminded of the thing and then there should be an option to repeat it on date x at time x and date y at time y

Comment: I would just leave the positive and negative buttons as is then and just make your layout via xml

Answer (score 1):

It seems more to me that that 'dialog' is an activity with a dialog theme, try this:

```
 <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Comment: But I'm wanting the dialog to pop up in front of the the current page. I don't want the app to open up a new page completely.

Comment: Thats what theme dialog does, opens the activity on top like a dialog

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend creating the layout you've supplied as it's too complex for mobile. But a simplified version with 1 option per line could be created.

You can see all supported Buttons, options, etc supported for AlertDialog.Builder in [the official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html).

As @TronicZomB pointed out, you can use your own XML layout with [setView(View view)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29).